# Is my own PKI based end-to-end encryption secure?

Tags: end-to-end-encryption

I implemented a simple chat that (tries to) encrypt messages end-to-end. I approached this problem by making both parties generate an ECDH keypair (P-384) and consequently share their public keys. Then, using one's own private key and the other's public key, I derive an AES shared key to encrypt and decrypt my messages. Assuming this is running on HTTPS:

- Is this a reliable end-to-end encryption?
- Is the additional encryption bad because I'm already using HTTPS?
- I'm not sure if I need HMAC and if so, how do I add it to my system?
- Can this be used for a conversation with more than 2 parties?

Comment: When do you rotate AES shared key? Do you address post-compromise security? https is for client to server security and e2e is for user to user. You need both.

Comment: How does each side know it has the correct public key for the other side rather than the public key of an attacker impersonating each person to the other?

Comment: I do not rotate the AES key but I added it to my todo. For the public key, I looked up how to validate this and I'm not sure how to proceed. At first I thought HTTPS was protecting me against this but it seems not. Should I generate the keys using a passphrase ?

Comment: You can use Signal protocol library. It has everything implemented for what should be there in e2ee.

Comment: Except the goal of the project is to do it myself. So no but I will read on it to know how they achieved some of my current roadblocks.